# Why is an image formed when two light rays coming from an object intercept?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

Why is an image formed when two light(one to the focus and one to the lens perpendicularly from the top of the object) rays coming from an object intercept?

Comment: You are using these two specific rays of light because you can ***easily*** construct the edge of object from these two. The image itself is formed from many rays "starting" from each point of the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about either lenses or mirrors. In order for one of these systems to form a real image, all of the light rays coming from a single point on the object must converge at a corresponding point in space. Like @npojo said, there are certain rays coming from the object that are easy to draw by hand in diagrams, so we use those. But to form in image we must have light rays from each point on the object converging at a corresponding point in space.

This applet is fun to play around with this. It shows only 3 rays from different points of the object, but in fact every ray from each point is converging at the corresponding image point.

http://labs.minutelabs.io/Lenses/

Comment: If all light rays converge at a single point then how do we get the whole image? It should be a point.

Comment: I am not saying every light ray from the object converges at a single point. I am saying for each point on the object the light rays coming from that point needs to converge  at a corresponding point in space. This is what forms the image. Point 1 converges at point 1', 2 at 2', etc.

Comment: Since in the system of lens and object two rays come from a single point and converge. Would it spoil the image?

Comment: In order to have an image you need multiple rays converging at a point in space from a corresponding point on the object. If this is not happening then you do not have an image. In the applet move the screen around and notice how you do not get a well focused image if your screen is not at the point in space where the light rays converge.

Comment: Look here.https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197039/

Comment: As an IMPORTANT remark: all that has been said in this post is fulfilled in the paraxial (Gaussian) regime, in which imaging forming is perfect. Further, the image location and magnification can be easily obtained by graphical methods (tracing rays) knowing the location of only two pairs of cardinal points (planes), or one pair of cardinal points (planes) and a pair of conjugate planes (one being the image of the other).